# Dynamic html generation div id trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am building this feature that dynamically outputs a new "panel" (some piece of html). The issue, however, is that the newly created div lacks an id, despite me explicitly assigning it one. The id is supposed to be a name with a number that increments on each generation of a new div (name1, name2, etc.). But I cannot get the div to accept the id that I am assigning it.

```
//add panel
  var i = 1; 
        $('#panel').click(function() { 
        $('body').append("<div id='photoContent" + i + "'><h1> Panel </h1><div id='showTable'><h2>add image</h2><div id='table'></div></div></div>").css({
            'margin' : '0px', 
            'padding' : '0px',
            'height' : height, 
            'width' : width,
            'background-color' : 'yellow', 
            'color' : 'rgba(192, 192, 192, .9)',
            'font-family' : 'sans-serif', 
            'font-size' : '40px',
            'text-align' : 'center',
            'border' : '2px solid rgba(192, 192, 192, 1)',
            'border-left-style' : 'none',
            'border-right-style' : 'none'
        }); //close css object literal; 
i++; }); //end click function
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your code.

It works if you remove this comment the code:

```
//some css
```

Which is inside of

```
.css ({//some css});
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle without .css](http://jsfiddle.net/48yqG/1/).

Here's a working [jsfiddle with .css](http://jsfiddle.net/48yqG/3/)

**What's the problem?**

The right parenthesis are commented out, therefor you have a very obvious syntax error, it will simply look like this:

```
 .css ({ uh, oh, no right parenthesis :(
```

**Edit**

You updated the code, you removed the comment which was causing the error, your solution works fine like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ufff3/1/) shows.

> The id is supposed to be a name with a number that increments on each generation of a new div (name1, name2, etc.). But I cannot get the div to accept the id that I am assigning it.

If I click the panel 2 times the following html is created:

```
<div id="photoContent1"><h1> Panel </h1><div id="showTable"><h2>add image</h2><div id="table"></div></div></div>
<div id="photoContent2"><h1> Panel </h1><div id="showTable"><h2>add image</h2><div id="table"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the response, so I should have been clearer, its not that the html does not generate, its that the divs that get generated do not take the ids that I assign. I am sure that the css is not the problem, I just tacked that on so I didnt have to obfuscate the code with the entire object literal.

Comment: Did you check the demo I linked? Your code works fine after my fix, it creates divs with id photoContent1, phontoContent2, and so on. the `.css` is the problem because you comment out the right parenthesis. I'm sure your developer tools console will tell you the same.

Comment: it was not the css, as I already mentioned. The problem came from something different.

Comment: @nmac I am aware that .css was not the problem but the comment inside of it. That's what I ment. What's the problem now? It works as indented.

Comment: check the update on the question. this time I included the code as its written verbatim. As you can see, no css is commented out, I only did that clumsily to copy and paste it quickly.

Comment: And now, if you'd look at the demo I added in the **edit** part of my answers, you can see that your solution works just fine. It creates more divs when you click on the panel div and they get id photoContent1, photoContent2 and so on.